# Как найти координаты пересечения двух отрезков зная их концы и угол при пересечении?

Tags: javascript, геометрия, вычислительная-геометрия

У меня есть координаты двух точек. А(1,7) и Б(8, 2). В коде, угол пересечения прямых, из этих точек, будет динамическим от 90 до -90 градусов (на картинке я показал угол). и для примера взял угол в 45 градусов.

От того какой угол я задам, мне надо будет отрисовать точку С по найденным координатам, но как их найти?

Какая последовательность действий мне нужна?

Снизу я добавил картинки того, как должны выглядеть прямые, если я задам угол в 90 и -90 градусов

**Точка С лежит на диагонали**

[image: пример задачи]

[image: как будут выглядеть прямые, если я задам угол 90 или -90 градусов]

Comment: ну задача хорошая - а вы сами то пытались что то сделать ?

Comment: @MaximLensky вопрос не всегда предполагает, что автор что-то должен был пытаться.

Comment: @Kromster тогда это задание  ?

Comment: @MaximLensky да, как я понял нужна теорема косинусов
AB^2=AC^2+BC^2-(2*AC*BC*сos(C))
AB^2 - я могу посчитать
сos(C) - я тоже могу посчитать

а как найти AC и BC на JS. 


да и вообще я уже сомневаюсь что я правильно думаю)))

Comment: @MaximLensky всё, в некотором приближении - задание. В данном случае, ТС сформулировал свою проблему своими словами. Формулировка достаточно ясна и в будущем пригодится тем, у кого будет аналогичный вопрос. Какие именно попытки решения вы хотите увидеть? )

Comment: @Kromster я просто спросил у автора - он что то делал или просто скопипастил картинку и всё на этом = дайте готовое решение ...:))

Comment: @MaximLensky копипасту обычно видно. Здесь, похоже, не она. Так что прошу вас конструктивно подойти к делу )

Comment: очевидно таких точки 2

Comment: @Kromster хотя вопрос очень полезный и интересный

Comment: @MaximLensky поэтому я и хочу улучшить его, чтобы этот вопрос остался в базе знаний Stack Overflow ;-)

Comment: @Kromster, просто перепишите текст заново, не стоит в этом случае "править"

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, имеешь ввиду отраженную еще?

Comment: @Grundy ну да, для рисунка, справа от центра на нарисованной диагонали, если за ее пределами - то еще 2

Comment: А какая задача решается? Как бы тут не xy-problem...

Comment: я может и сам напишу код, только скажите какой ход действий.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ почему никто не может подсказать как делать, если все пишут что это легко?)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, Судя по обозначениям углов на рисунке, для отраженной точки  на диагонали угол будет -45

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Аналитическое решение для этой задачи есть, но у меня получилось очень громоздкое. Поэтому предлагаю численно подобрать решение бинарным поиском. Код на Python. dx, dy - ширина и высота, an - угол в радианах. Ответ - два смещения от вершины.

```
from math import sqrt, cos, pi
def calcpos(dx, dy, an):
    l = 0
    r = 0.5
    cosa = cos(an)
    dx2 = dx * dx
    dy2 = dy * dy
    dxdy = dx2 + dy2
    while (r - l > 0.0001):
        t = (l + r) / 2
        tt = 1 - t
        ca = dxdy * t * tt / sqrt((dx2 * t * t + dy2 * tt * tt)*(dy2 * t * t + dx2 * tt * tt))
        if ca > cosa:
            r = t
        else:
            l = t
    return [(dx * l, dy * (1 - l)), (dx * (1 - l), dy * l)]

print(calcpos(2, 3, pi/4))

>> [(0.5621337890625, 2.15679931640625), (1.4378662109375, 0.84320068359375)]
```

Проверочка (углы показаны дополнительные до 180):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вот этот вариант:
coords1 - координаты точки А;
coords2 - координаты точки B;
angle - угол от 90 до -90;

```
function normalize0between1(min, max, value){
    return (value - min) / (max - min);
}


function getCoords(coords1, coords2, angle) {
    let { x1, y1 } = coords1;
    let { x2, y2 } = coords2;
    let hypo = Math.sqrt((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));
    let offset = hypo * normalize0between1(90, -90, angle);
    let computedAngle = Math.asin((y1 - y2) / hypo);
    let _x = Math.cos(computedAngle) * offset + x1;
    let _y = Math.sin(computedAngle) * offset + y2;
    return {
        x: _x,
        y: _y
    };
}

let coords = getCoords({x1: 1, y1: 7}, {x2: 8, y2: 2}, -90);

console.log(coords);
```

Comment: А что здесь происходит?